# WCF client server Application

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to create 2 applications. i.e, 1 for client and another 1 for server. Client app will be installed in so many computers and service should be run automatically. 
If i open the server app, i need the client computer details and select the computer and send some operation like shutdown. then the client computer should execute the shutdown code and it should be turned off.
Please can u tell what type of concepts i have to use in Windows communication service. I'm new to Windows communication service.

Comment: This question is too broad to effectively give you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you  need is a duplex communication you  can start with wsDualHttpBinding the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491844/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Duplex-WCF) bellow provide a good  example for starting, and in  second time you can host your service in windows  service on  both client and server  something like in  this  [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

hope  this help